# How to populate a tree structure?

Tags: c#, tree

I have a list of `MyObject1`:

```
public class MyObject1
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int ParentId {get; set;}
}

List<MyObject1> list = new List<MyObject1>();
```

I need to build a tree using `MyObject2`:

```
public class MyObject2
    {
       public int Id {get; set;}
       public int ParentId {get; set;}
       // Here should be all child objects, that have .ParentId property is 
       // equal to .Id property of current node
       public List<MyObject2> Children = new List<MyObject2>();
    }
```

What is the fastest way to do that ? Maybe I should to sort my `list` by `Id` or `ParentId` before building ?

**ETA**
My try:

```
MyObject2 root = MyObject2(1, 0); // in constructor id, parentId 

foreach (MyObject1 obj1 in list)
{
  // Traversing all tree within root (let's say myTree), 
  //if myTree.ParentId = obj1.Id then:

  myTree.Children.Add(new MyObject2(obj1.Id, obj1.ParentId));
}
```

The problem is what if there's no any object with such `.Id` in the tree yet ?
This is the best way to that ?

Comment: You'll probably be best off sorting by parentID & then Id within those buckets

Comment: Why are you searching for `fastest way`? your way isn't fast enough? What have you tried?

Comment: @I4V Why I should search for the slowest way to do that ? I'm a new in c#, that's why I'm asking it

Comment: @William `What is the best/fastest way` type of questions imply simply *write the code for me*. You should show some effort to solve your own question before asking help from people.

Comment: @I4V, Of course I've tried, just thought that it's not necessary to prove it to other people

Comment: @William see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211609/porting-code-containing-unsigned-char-pointer-in-c-to-c-sharp . OP doesn't simply ask *"how can I port this to C#"* and posts what he has tried so far. I think a question that deserves an answer should be like that (of course if answerable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<MyObject2> result = new List<MyObject2>(){new MyObject2(1, 0)};
Dictionary<int, List<MyObject2>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<MyObject2>>();

foreach (MyObject1 obj1 in list)
{
    MyObject2 tmp = new MyObject2(obj1.Id, obj1.ParentId);
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(tmp.ParentId))
    {
        dict.Add(tmp.ParentId, new List<MyObject2>());
    }
    dict[tmp.ParentId].Add(tmp);
    result.Add(tmp);
}

foreach (MyObject2 obj2 in result)
{
    if(dict.ContainsKey(obj2.Id))
        obj2.Children = dict[obj2.Id];
}
```

Keep in mind that if you change a `List<MyObject2>` of `dict`, you are also changing the `Children` of the corresponding parent.

Comment: But in `result` will be all nodes at the first(root) level, and they will be having their child objects, so it's like the same nodes will be repeated twice

Comment: `result` should be not a `List` but one root node, and every other nodes should be in `root.Children` and etc. And root node is `new MyObject2(1, 0)`. Or maybe I misunderstand something ?

Comment: @William `result` is not the final tree structure, but a way to loop over the nodes. Once it is done, the `Children` of each node will be setted, and with `MyObject2 root = result[0];` you will have the root node.

Comment: thank you, my bad. Now I return only root node, so I think the only way to travers my tree(for search or edit specific nodes) within root node is using recursion, am I right ?

Comment: @William Not necessarily, you can also use an iterative algorithm to perform the search ([Pseudocode for DFS and BFS](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~markn/395/pdf/dfs_bfs.pdf))

Comment: Excellent answer! This helped me a lot today at work. I though I'd let you know.