# Porting code containing unsigned char pointer in C to C#

Tags: c#, c, encryption

I have this code in C that I need to port to C#:

```
void CryptoBuffer(unsigned char *Buffer, unsigned short length)
{
    unsigned short i;
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *Buffer ^= 0xAA;
        *Buffer++ += 0xC9;
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
public void CryptoBuffer(byte[] buffer, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] ^= 0xAA;
        buffer[i] += 0xC9;
    }
}
```

But the outcome doesn't match the one expected.

According to the example, this:

```
A5 03 18 01...
```

should become this:

```
A5 6F 93 8B...
```

It also says the first byte is not encrypted, so that's why A5 stays the same.

**EDIT for clarification**: The specification just says you should skip the first byte, it doesn't go into details, so I'm guessing you just pass the sequence from position 1 until the last position to skip the first byte.

But my outcome with that C# port is:

```
A5 72 7B 74...
```

Is this port correct or am I missing something?

**EDIT 2**: For further clarification, this is a closed protocol, so I can't go into details, that's why I provided just enough information to help me port the code, that C code was the one that was given to me, and that's what the specification said it would do.
The real problem was that the "0xAA" was wrong in the specification, that's why the output wasn't the expected one. The C# code provided here and by the accepted answer are correct after all.

Comment: That is some seriously hard to read C code. Who thinks it is a good idea to mix dereferencing, incrementing, addition and assignment in one expression?

Comment: Given your example input, I get the same answer for C and C#, except for the first byte (as you've given no indication in the code as to why it is skipped).

Comment: @Eric: Kernighan and Ritchie did seem to be fond of that kind of code, if my memory of reading The C Programming Language back in the '80s serves... ;) Their example of strcpy looked like `while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0');` ... Shudder

Comment: Actually, system side code *fooPtr++ is a common construct.  There are other ways to write it, but I've seen compilers screw up optimization on it many times outside of that notation.  Although the += on the backside is a bit over the top :)

Comment: Hmm, that += my be the reason this is failing as when the add is occuring may be different on the C# side - which byte is being added to?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It may be common. Doesn't make it a good idea though.

Comment: Before asking about the C# code, why don't you track down why the C code doesn't do what you claim it to do?

Comment: So, I vote to close as *not a real question* since the C code does not produce the desired output. And in fact produces the same output as the C# code.

Comment: Agree - either post the actual C code or point us to the specification; as stated, this question can't be answered.

Comment: If you need to port the code, just port it :) the port is correct. Specifications change (but spec documents don't get updated so often), maybe at the time the spec was written the example was created based on a different "crypto" function. Or the person writing it made a mistake and gave a wrong/misleading example, which never got checked or corrected.

Comment: @JoaquimRendeiro: Do you know what's the specification OP talking about? Since I do not ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's break it down shall we, one step at a time.

```
void CryptoBuffer(unsigned char *Buffer, unsigned short length)
{
    unsigned short i;
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *Buffer ^= 0xAA;
        *Buffer++ += 0xC9;
    }
}
```

Regardless of some other remarks, this *is* how you normally do these things in C/C++. There's nothing fancy about this code, and it isn't overly complicated, but I think it is good to break it down to show you what happens.

Things to note:

1. unsigned char is basically the same as byte in c#
2. unsigned length has a value between 0-65536. Int should do the trick.
3. Buffer has a post-increment
4. The byte assignment (+= 0xC9) will overflow. If it overflows it's truncated to 8 bits in this case.
5. The buffer is passed by ptr, so the pointer in the calling method will stay the same.
6. This is just basic C code, no C++. It's quite safe to assume people don't use operator overloading here.

The only "difficult" thing here is the Buffer++. Details can be read in the book "Exceptional C++" from Sutter, but a small example explains this as well. And fortunately we have a perfect example at our disposal. A **literal** translation of the above code is:

```
void CryptoBuffer(unsigned char *Buffer, unsigned short length)
{
    unsigned short i;
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *Buffer ^= 0xAA;
        unsigned char *tmp = Buffer;
        *tmp += 0xC9;
        Buffer = tmp + 1;
    }
}
```

In this case the temp variable can be solved trivially, which leads us to:

```
void CryptoBuffer(unsigned char *Buffer, unsigned short length)
{
    unsigned short i;
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *Buffer ^= 0xAA;
        *Buffer += 0xC9;
        ++Buffer;
    }
}
```

Changing this code to C# now is pretty easy:

```
private void CryptoBuffer(byte[] Buffer, int length)
{
    for (int i=0; i<length; ++i) 
    {
        Buffer[i] = (byte)((Buffer[i] ^ 0xAA) + 0xC9);
    }
}
```

**This is basically the same as your ported code.** This means that somewhere down the road something else went wrong... So let's hack the cryptobuffer shall we? :-)

If we assume that the first byte isn't used (as you stated) and that the '0xAA' and/or the '0xC9' are wrong, we can simply try all combinations:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] orig = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x18, 0x01 };
    byte[] target = new byte[] { 0x6F, 0x93, 0x8b };

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j)
        {
            bool okay = true;
            for (int k = 0; okay && k < 3; ++k)
            {
                byte tmp = (byte)((orig[k] ^ i) + j);
                if (tmp != target[k]) { okay = false; break; }
            }
            if (okay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Solution for i={0} and j={1}", i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

There we go: **oops** there are no solutions. That means that the cryptobuffer is not doing what you think it's doing, or part of the C code is missing here. F.ex. do they really pass 'Buffer' to the CryptoBuffer method or did they change the pointer before?

Concluding, I think the only good answer here is that critical information for solving this question is missing.

Comment: Thanks Ken Kin. More information from @Mahmoud would be helpful though, so we can really solve this.

Comment: As it turns out the problem really was that the C code didn't do what the specification said it would, so that's why the port wasn't "working", both mine port and yours work after the correct specification was passed.
The key "0xAA" wasn't correct, it is actually a string of 8 different values. I can't post them here because it is a key that is supposed to be private, but thanks for the help answering the question.

Comment: @Mahmoud ... well, for one thing, I sincerely hope you also learned from my answer that breaking a security algorithm using just 'xor' and 'add' is child play for a hacker... a brute force algorithm will break it in the blink of an eye. If you need security, use something that has been proven to be applicable in that context.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn yes, that's the first thing I thought when I saw it too, but that's a communication protocol from a manufacturer's device, so unfortunately I can't change it. In fact, we did find the correct key using brute force because we didn't get an answer fast enough from the manufacturer and we suspected the problem was the key after all.

Answer (score 5):

The example you were provided with is inconsistent with the code in the C sample, and the C and C# code produce identical results.

Answer (score 3):

The porting looks right; can you explain why 03 should become 6F? The fact that the result seems to be off the "expected" value by 03 is a bit suspicious to me.

Comment: The specification shows that as an example. It also says you should always skip the first byte.

Comment: @Mahmoud: you need to say what specification you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The port *looks* right.

What I would do in this situation is to take out a piece of paper and a pen, write out the bytes in binary, do the XOR, and then the addition. Now compare this to the C and C# codes.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you are overflowing the byte so it gets truncated to 0x72.  Here's the math for converting the 0x03 in both binary and hex:

```
   00000011   0x003
^  10101010   0x0AA
=  10101001   0x0A9
+  11001001   0x0C9
= 101110010   0x172
```

Answer (score 0):

With the original method in C, we first suppose the sequence is decrypted/encrypted in a **symmetric** way with calling `CryptoBuffer`

- initially invoke on `a5 03 18 01 ...`

  ```
  a5 03 18 01 ... => d8 72 7b 74 ...
  ```

  then on `d8 72 7b 74 ...`

  ```
  d8 72 7b 74 ... => 3b a1 9a a7 ...
  ```
- initially invoke on `a5 6f 93 8b ...`

  ```
  a5 6f 93 8b ... => d8 8e 02 ea ...
  ```

  then on `d8 8e 02 ea ...`

  ```
  d8 8e 02 ea ... => 3b ed 71 09 ...
  ```

and we know it's not feasible.

Of course, you might have an **asymmetric** decrypt method; but first off, we would need either `a5 03 18 01 ... => a5 6f 93 8b ...` or the reverse of direction been proved with any possible magic number. The code of an analysis with a **brute force approach** is put at the rear of post.

I made the magic number been a variable for testing. With **reproducibility analysis**, we found that the original sequence can be reproduced every 256 invocation on continuously varied magic number. Okay, with what we've gone through it's still possible here.

However, the **feasibility analysis** which tests all of `256*256=65536` cases with both direction, from `original => expected` and `expected => original`, and none makes it.

And now we know there is no way to decrypt the encrypted sequence to the expected result.

Thus, we can only tell that the **expected behavior of both language or your code are identical**, but for the **expected result is not possible** because of the assumption was broken.

---

Code for the analysis

```
public void CryptoBuffer(byte[] buffer, ushort magicShort) {
    var magicBytes=BitConverter.GetBytes(magicShort);
    var count=buffer.Length;

    for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
        buffer[i]^=magicBytes[1];
        buffer[i]+=magicBytes[0];
    }
}

int Analyze(
    Action<byte[], ushort> subject,
    byte[] expected, byte[] original,
    ushort? magicShort=default(ushort?)
    ) {
    Func<byte[], String> LaHeX= // narrowing bytes to hex statement
        arg => arg.Select(x => String.Format("{0:x2}\x20", x)).Aggregate(String.Concat);

    var temporal=(byte[])original.Clone();
    var found=0;

    for(var i=ushort.MaxValue; i>=0; --i) {
        if(found>255) {
            Console.WriteLine(": might found more than the number of square root; ");
            Console.WriteLine(": analyze stopped ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
        }

        subject(temporal, magicShort??i);

        if(expected.SequenceEqual(temporal)) {
            ++found;
            Console.WriteLine("i={0:x2}; temporal={1}", i, LaHeX(temporal));
        }

        if(expected!=original)
            temporal=(byte[])original.Clone();
    }

    return found;
}

void PerformTest() {
    var original=new byte[] { 0xa5, 0x03, 0x18, 0x01 };
    var expected=new byte[] { 0xa5, 0x6f, 0x93, 0x8b };

    Console.WriteLine("--- reproducibility analysis --- ");
    Console.WriteLine("found: {0}", Analyze(CryptoBuffer, original, original, 0xaac9));
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("--- feasibility analysis --- ");
    Console.WriteLine("found: {0}", Analyze(CryptoBuffer, expected, original));
    Console.WriteLine();

    // swap original and expected
    var temporal=original;
    original=expected;
    expected=temporal;

    Console.WriteLine("--- reproducibility analysis --- ");
    Console.WriteLine("found: {0}", Analyze(CryptoBuffer, original, original, 0xaac9));
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("--- feasibility analysis --- ");
    Console.WriteLine("found: {0}", Analyze(CryptoBuffer, expected, original));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration

http://codepad.org/UrX0okgu

shows that the original code, given an input of `A5 03 18 01` produces `D8 72 7B 01`; so

1. rule that the first byte is not decoded can be correct only if the buffer is sent starting from 2nd (show us the call)
2. the output does not match (do you miss other calls?)

So your translation is correct but your expectations on what the original code does are not.